# Bash for every x files create sub folder and move files there

Tags: shell, dash

I am looking for an alternative dash command I can use
as I am trying to execute the code from within python
and due to the fact that the sub folder has 100's of files I am am trying to group into folders of 10 I dont want my python script getting in the way.

the command I am trying is not working in dash due to the "<()"
and I am looking for an alternative.

Code:

```
i=0;while read l;do mkdir folder$i;mv $l folder$((i++));done< <(ls|xargs -n10)
```

Error:

```
Syntax error: redirection unexpected
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? This isn't a very good approach because of the [problems](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) inherent in parsing the output of `ls`, but it isn't _wrong_ per se, it should work in bash. Are you sure you are using bash here?

Comment: it works in bash but the problem is I am executing the command from python so due to the two "< <" its not working. So looking for another terminal command I can use instead.

Comment: Then please add that to your question! Python will be using your system's `/bin/sh` which won't be `bash` but either a simple POSIX shell like `dash` (this will be the case on Ubuntu, for example) or bash but in POSIX mode. IN any case it won't be the normal bash. And it isn't the two `<` that are the problem, it is the `<()`. But if you're using python, why don't you just do it in python?

Comment: because the task i am preforming is in a sub directory from where my python script is. the full script is:    
beep = """cd directory && i=0;while read l;do mkdir folder$i;mv $l folder$((i++));done< <(ls|xargs -n10)"""
cmd = os.popen(beep)
print(cmd.read())
print(cmd.close())

Comment: So? That shouldn't be a problem. I will post a shell solution, but I strongly urge you to look at your python code a bit more closely. There is no reason to do this in the shell from within a python script. You might want to post a question on [so] with your python code.

Comment: You don't need to `cd` at all. Just use `for file in directory/*`.

Answer (score 2):

That code works in bash, but it won't work in POSIX shells because the `<()` command substitution format isn't portable and when calling a shell from your python script you are almost certainly launching `/bin/sh` which is either not bash at all (e.g. `dash` on many Debian-based systems) or `bash` in POSIX mode, or some other basic POSIX shell. In any case, this isn't a very safe approach since it suffers from [the problems](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) inherent in parsing `ls`.

Here's another approach:

```bsh
k=0 
for file in *; do 
    [ "$k" = 10 ] && k=0
    mkdir -p folder"$k"
    mv -- "$file" "folder$k"
    k=$((k+1))
done
```

Note that the `mkdir -p` is also not portable, as the `-p` option (don't complain if the directory already exists) isn't supported by all `mkdir` implementations. If that's a problem, you can either add code to test for the existence of the target directory or just ignore the error messages.

All this said, if you are writing a Python script, then you really should do all this natively in Python instead of calling an external shell. There's no reason this cannot be done in Python, you mentioned that it needs to happen in a different directory, but that isn't a problem at all. I urge you to look at your Python code a bit more closely and implement this in Python instead.

For example, here's a python script to do the same thing:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import shutil
import sys

# read the first argument into source_dir
source_dir = sys.argv[1]

dir_counter = 0
file_counter = 0

target_dir = os.path.join(source_dir, "folder")

for file_name in os.listdir(source_dir):
    # If this is a file
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        file_counter += 1
        # If this file number is a multiple of 10,
        # change the target dir name
        if file_counter % 10 == 0:
            dir_counter += 1
            target_dir = os.path.join(source_dir, "folder" + str(dir_counter))
        # Create the dir if it doesn't exist
        if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
            os.mkdir(target_dir)
        try:
            shutil.move(file_name, target_dir)
        except Exception as error_message:
            print("Failed to move %s to %s with error %s" %
                  (file_name, target_dir, error_message))
```

Then, run the script with the source directory as an argument:

```
foo.py /path/to/source/directory
```

This isn't a particularly elegant python script, I am sure it can be significantly improved, but it should give you an idea of the kind of thing that is possible.

Comment: thank you for your help, the thing is i am a novice in python so most of the time I rely heavily on shell commands. wherever possible using os.popen(command) are you saying that most shell commands can and should be written natively in python?

Comment: @jessyjack yes, exactly. Python, and any other proper scripting language, can do everything the shell can do and it can do it better. You only need to use `os.popen(command)` to run non-shell commands, really. For things like what you show, basic file manipulation, it doesn't make sense to use the shell from within a python script. Have a look at the simple python script I added.

Comment: I think you could use the modulo operator even in a POSIX shell, like `k=$(( (k+1) % 10 ))` or so

Comment: What are you doing with the `$i` variable?

Comment: @RudiC lol, absolutely nothing, it was left over from an earlier approach I was trying but didn't end up using. Fixed now, thanks!

Comment: +1 for "you should do this natively in python".  python can create directories and rename files, there's no need to fork a shell to do either of those things.